# Changing Filenames with python, whilst using some of the old name

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

Im currently working on a Python script wich will upload a file from a directory onto an FTP server wich is build into a 3D Printer. Everything with upload and FTP works, but i have a rather specific task to do for the script. I want to dump a lot of files into the starting directory. So it goes like:

1. 1474lapfab.tgz
2. 1475lapfab.tgz
3. ...lapfab.tgz
4. ..........

I want the script to grab the first file and modify the name so it only sends lapfab.tgz (lapfab.tgz being the filename the printer reacts to so it has to be this name) to the ftp server. But here is the specific part. I want a new Variable wich holds the number at the beginning, so i can display the current number of project the printer ist working on.

My Code so Far

```
# -*- coding: cp1252 -*-
#geschrieben in Python 2.7.1
#Drucker Rechts
import ftplib
import os

meinftp = ftplib.FTP("192.168.178.178")
meinftp.login("anonymous")

directory = '/data/todo/'                               #Ftp Main Directory
meinftp.cwd(directory)                                  #Login to right ftp directory
directory_local='/home/pi/testprogramme/python/'        #Local upload directory
filename = 'lapfab.tgz'

print "Open file"
print
file = open(directory_local+filename, 'rb')             #Open file in Binary

print "Upload File"

meinftp.storbinary('Stor '+filename, file)              #File Transfer

print
print "Upload Complete"
print
print 'The local File ' + filename +' will close.'

file.close()

print
print meinftp.quit()                                    #Kill Conection
print
print 'FTP-Connection cut.'

os.remove('lapfab')                                     #Deleting the main File from server

print
print  "Deleting Main File from Server"
```

If someone could send me on the right track from here on to geht my task done, that would be more than great!

Greetings from Germany and appologys for bad english.

Best Regards Eddie =)

EDIT:

I works, If you would like to make something like this use the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: cp1252 -*-
#geschrieben in Python 2.7.1
#Drucker Rechts
import ftplib, os, re, fnmatch

meinftp = ftplib.FTP("192.168.178.178")
meinftp.login("anonymous")

directory = '/data/todo/'                               #Ftp Main Directory
meinftp.cwd(directory)                                  #Login to right ftp directory
directory_local='/home/pi/testprogramme/python/'        #Local upload directory
filename = 'lapfab.tgz'

# Capture the matching files.
file_pattern = "*%s" % filename
matches = sorted([local_filename for local_filename in os.listdir(directory_local) \
if fnmatch.fnmatch(local_filename, file_pattern)])

if len(matches) < 0:
    # Don ^ ^ t process anything, no files
    exit()

# Extract the variable
regex = r"([0-9]+)%s" % filename
match = re.search(regex, matches[0])

# Do something with the file.
print("Uploading job %s." % match.group(1))
full_path = os.path.join(directory_local,matches[0])

# Upload the file etc here.





print "Open file"
print
file = open(full_path, 'rb')            #Open file in Binary

print "Upload File"

meinftp.storbinary('Stor '+filename, file)              #File Transfer

print
print "Upload Complete"
print
print 'The local File ' + filename +' will close.'

file.close()

print
print meinftp.quit()                                    #Kill Conection
print
print 'FTP-Connection cut.'

os.remove(full_path)                                    #Deleting the main File from server

print
print  "Deleting Main File from Server"
print
print "The File" +full_path+ " was transfered to the Right Printer"
print
print
print "End!"
print
```

I used a second Script to run this one on a buttonpush. It works like a charm and will from now on help me get my work done more efficent.
Thanks for the help. And have a nice coding.
Best Regards,
Eddie =)

Comment: `os.remove('lapfab')` probably will not do what the comment next to it claims it does.

Comment: You are partly right. it will work but the comment is misleading. I translated the comments from german to english and made a mistake. it does NOT delete the main file from the server on the printer. it will delete the main file in the pi itself. i only need the file on the printer and not on the pi =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've read your question right, there's two parts to solve:

1. How to upload multiple files from the local directory.
2. How to extract the variable name from the file name.

For 1, you can use os.listdir() to get a list of files in the local directory. For 2, you can use a regular expression to capture the variable out of the file name. Use a regex capture group in parentheses - () to capture the variable. Regular expressions are in the re module.

```
import re

regex = r"([0-9]+)%s" % filename # This will give you r"([0-9]+)lapfab.tgz"
match = re.search(regex, "1474lapfab.tgz")
print match.group(0) # This will print out "1474lapfab.tgz".
print match.group(1) # This will print out "1474".
```

If you combine the two, you can iterate the local directory and capture the variable name:

```
import os, re, fnmatch

directory_local = '/home/pi/testprogramme/python/' #Local upload directory
filename = 'lapfab.tgz'

# Capture the matching files.
file_pattern = "*%s" % filename
matches = sorted([local_filename for local_filename in os.listdir(directory_local) \
if fnmatch.fnmatch(local_filename, file_pattern)])

if len(matches) < 0:
    # Don’t process anything, no files
    return # or exit()

# Extract the variable
regex = r"([0-9]+)%s" % filename
match = re.search(regex, matches[0])

# Do something with the file.
print("Uploading job %s." % match.group(1))
full_path = os.path.join(directory_local,matches[0])

# Upload the file etc here.
```

Some more resources on regular expressions you might find helpful:

- [This page](https://regexone.com/references/python) has a better overview of using regular expressions in python
- [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/#python) is useful for playing with and debugging regexes to see if they match, outside of your program.

Comment: You got my point pretty well but i dont want to upload many files. i only want to upload a single file at a time to the 3d printer. the pi has its own ftp server installed on wich i will upload all the files. i will add another script wich watches a pushbutton and activates this script to upload the next lapfab file in the list acording to the number in the beginning.

Comment: Got you. The basic approach should still work. I've edited the answer to skip non-matching files. The script won't know the exact file name when it runs, so it will get the list of files in the directory, check the file name pattern, and then process it if it matches.

Comment: Ok i will try to impliment it in just a minute. but one question, will this use the first in the list aka the file with the lowest number? thats important because i need the printer to work in order. Greetings

Comment: So i got it going. and it seemed that he only uploadet 1 file but the comand line said he uploaded everything. 
comand line:

`Uploading job 1481.
Uploading job 1480.
Open file

Upload File

Upload Complete

The local File lapfab.tgz will close.

221 Goodbye.

FTP-Connection cut.`

any idea whats the problem here?
and like i said i need the lower file to be uploaded first. is there a way to change the order around? =) you helped me a lot with this already. if i get this last bit done im a happy potatoe. Greetings

Comment: Ok, I think I understand now. There might be multiple files in the directory, but you just want the lowest numbered one to be uploaded.

Comment: What you want to do is capture all the matching files, sort them and then pick the lowest match. So, something like:

Comment: Whoops, sorry, can't drive a comments box. I've updated the answer with a version that should help. Hopefully it answers your question now. Good luck!

Comment: made some updates to my main Question. If we get this last bit done it would be awesome!

Comment: I think I know what it is - I've updated my answer a little. I'd written os.listdir("."), when I was testing the syntax, but it should have been os.listdir(local_directory).

Comment: Allright Mr. it is working! thank you so much! i will update the working code in my question in just a bit. this was a fun experiment. Thanks for the Great help!